# how set a divider in evey next line with wrap widget?

Tags: android, flutter, divider

I want to add a line or divider in each line in wrap widget,when i use wrap my item are in next line but  I cant show a divider befor next line.
I want to creat  wrap items like below picture:
https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/770204703321489408/776052658556764160/Screenshot_20201111-152557_Duolingo.jpg

Comment: Hi, please were you able to find the solution to this?

Answer (score -1):

```
Container(
   height: 1,
   child: Container(color: Colors.grey),
)
```

Comment: Hi Ash. While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value. [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Kind Regards.

Comment: hi.this code isnt useful,beacause i want to use divider in dinamic wrap widget,i want to add divider every line in wrap widget or flaxible row but automatically.